# Splitting a string based on specific characters

Tags: c#, string-parsing, split, equations, truthtable

I will try to describe my problem as well as I can.
I am trying to write a program that will handle equations like:

```
F = (X∨A) ↔ (X∨B) ( (X OR A) is equivalent to (X OR B) )!
```

I have to solve it by 'X', or to better say, write disjunctive and/or conjunctive normal form.

So, theoretically, it goes like this:

[image]

When the truth table is written, you have to see when F is equal to 1 (tautology), and write conjunctive/disjunctive normal form.

For example (disjunctive normal form for the given table):
For A=0,B=0 and A=1,B=1, the value of X does not matter, and for A=0,B=1 AND A=1,B=0, X must be 1.

[image]

In the end, 
X=A∨B.

Since I'm writing it in C#, equations are written in a TextBox.
What bothers me,is how should I separate my string so I can solve it part by part?

Comment: How about seperating by special chars like: '(', ')', '∨', '↔', [...]?

Comment: Title of question has no relevance with problem you are facing.

Comment: Is your question _"How do I split a string"_?

Comment: Yes,more like that. How do I split or manipulate string in order to get simpler equations?

Comment: I'm sorry if title has no relevance,but I'm finding difficulties with translating from one language to another,since I'm not fluent in english.
I don't seem to find a solution,if I write an equation like:
**A∨B↔-(A∨X)** ,how do I need to manipulate string so I can seperate that equation into F1= A∨B , F2 = -(A∨X) and F3 = F1↔F2

Comment: Take a look at my [math parser](https://nicoschertler.wordpress.com/2011/09/22/math-parser-using-lambda-expressions/). It requires some adaptation to the logic domain but the concept stays the same.

Comment: is it always such an ↔ equivalence equation entered? If so, why not use two textboxes, one for F1 and one for F2, that will save you that first hassle.

Comment: Nico,I'll take a look ,thanks. LocEngineer,the problem is,the equation could be simpler or more complex,and the equivalence is just an example.

Comment: I'm trying to get something like this - http://www.ee.umd.edu/~yavuz/logiccalc.html

Answer (score 0):

What about first trying "Split()" method (or other methods) of the class String in C#? In the first place, you'd better push your users to insert a blank (as the separator of Split()) between each pair of tokens (e.g. A AND B) , so that you can concentrate on the main logic of your solver.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I'm currently checking whether it is possible or not to do it with the Split() method.

Comment: I used the Split() method with the blank separator, and made an array of variables and operators from a string. Now, I could use "for loop" ,and check for an operator, but can I check for the previous and next array item?
For example,if i'm looking for an operator &, and wanted to check whether A is before,and B after the operator, is it OK to check it like this?

if(splitarray[i] == "&")
{
     if((splitarray[i-1]=="A")&&(splitarray[i+1])=="B"){some-logic}
}
Or would it send me an error for index out of bounds cause of i+1 element?

Comment: As far as I know, a 'tree', rather than an 'array,' is mostly appropriate for a (logical) expression. For instance, 'A AND B' makes a tree where 'AND' is the root node and 'A' and 'B' are left and right children, respectively. (You may check any compiler text book.) And using predefined tree-related APIs in C# would make your job much easier.

Comment: But if you have any special reasons to use an array instead of a tree, I think index bound checks are necessary. And in this case, List APIs seem better than raw typed arrays, because you can also get advantage of richness of Collection API of C# especially in checking status and handling errors.

Answer (score 0):

I see. It's basically a simplifying calculator that doesn't (necessarily) have sequential input via buttons but a ready-made formula typed or pasted in a textbox.

What you need to do is therefore

- define a set of permitted operators (AND, OR, NOT, XOR, etc.) in
  various permitted notations (Λ, V, !, =, !=, etc., +,*,-,=, ↔ etc.)
- check whether the input is syntactically correct; which means
  you'll probably have to first remove all spaces from the input
  string, then use regular expressions for allowed constructs, which
  will probably prove to be a pain
- if input is valid, check for parentheses first to determine grouped
  expressions
- simplify according to boolean algebra

**Or simply follow this link (Java but still):** [Boolean expression solver/simplifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13546791/boolean-expression-solver-simplifier), use the tool bc2cnf or any other library that is linked there and spare yourself a lot of headache by restricting the permitted input to one permitted by the used library.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. It actually doesn't matter if input is written from keyboard or via buttons, I'm looking for a solution that is easier. I have the option to restrict my propositional variables (A,B,C) to 2 or to 3.
I gave an example of the logic calculator made by someone else in the comments above -  ee.umd.edu/~yavuz/logiccalc.html
I can also assume that input will be syntactically correct,to remove the unnecessary pain for allowed constructs.

Comment: So,the main problem is,if I'm giving an input through buttons ( variables A,B,X and expressions AND,OR,NOT,IMPLIES ),how can I detect and resolve parts of equation, so I can,in the end,resolve the whole equation?

Comment: I think what you need is not to split the string but to parse it. You could replace all operators with their c# equivalent (replace "AND" with "&&") and use a truth table generator: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14925277/boolean-logic-truth-tables-and-outputs combined with bool.TryParse() to evaluate the string/string parts. You'll prob. have to parse the string char by char to decide when to evaluate based on operator precedence. I haven't done bool algebra for 18 years, sorry for not being more detailed.

Comment: I don't seem to understand what you wanted to say. If I parse the input string, bool.TryParse() will return the valuse true/false. And since my input has only letters (variables) A,B,X.. and logical operators &,|,- ,it will either throw an exception or return false?

Comment: I meant to use bool.Parse in order to create a truth table. Maybe I misunderstood this, I just thought you need to evaluate the parts of the equation, don't you?